# Multiple Magento Attributes on One Product

Tags: php, database, magento, e-commerce

Each of the products in my Magento store has attributes that are used as filters.  I would like to know if it is possible to give one product multiple attributes of the same type, or if there is an extension that makes this possible.

A specific example is this:  I'm selling safes, and my products need to be filterable by what types of objects they can hold.  For example, one particular safe might be designed to hold cash, documents, and valuables.  My problems is that I am currently using the general settings under product management, and I'm only able to add only one such attribute to each product.

Basically, the way I'm doing it now, a safe could be shown to hold cash, or documents, or valuables, but not all three.   I am looking for an extension or a programmatic way to get this done.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Dean, your issue is already resolved my Magento. All you need to do - is change the type of your "hold objects" attribute from "Dropdown" to "Multiple Select".

The bad news are - you actually can't change the attribute type directly in admin Attribute Management screen (Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes). So you'll have to create new attribute for your "Hold Objects" and choose the attribute type "Multiple Select".